# Exoplayer throws player is accessed on the wrong thread Exception

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

when I use `exoplayer` I get a `player is accessed on the wrong thread error`. How can I solve this?

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Player is accessed on the wrong 
thread.
Current thread: 'main'
Expected thread: 'ConnectivityThread'
See https://exoplayer.dev/issues/player-accessed-on-wrong-thread
```

The player is started as a service via my BackgroundAudioService.class.

```
exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()
            .build();
```

In the main thread my looper is running, the
which updates the UI via `exoplayer.getCurrentPosition()`.

```
public final Runnable updatePosition = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        position  = BackgroundAudioService.getCurrentPostion();
    }
}

myHandler.postDelayed(updatePosition, myHandlerSleep);
```

I don't know how to solve this problem (which occurs just sometimes), please help.

Thanks
Alejandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by calling the status via a handler in the player's event listener. Starting a `runnable` from the listener which runs only when `player.isPlaying() == true`.

```
     player.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvents(Player player, Player.Events events) {
            Player.Listener.super.onEvents(player, events);

            if (events.contains(Player.EVENT_IS_PLAYING_CHANGED)) {
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    positionHandler.postDelayed(getCurrentPositionTask,CURRENT_POSITION_SLEEP);

                } else {
                    positionHandler.removeCallbacks(getCurrentPositionTask);

                }
            }
        }
    });

    public Runnable getCurrentPositionTask = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (exoPlayer != null) {
            currentPostion = exoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            positionHandler.postDelayed(getCurrentPositionTask,CURRENT_POSITION_SLEEP);
        }            
    }
};
```

The UI calls the current position the same way in a runnable.

I can't say whether this is the best way. but it's going well.

GGK

Comment: this doesn't work for me. Playing some minutes will work, then exoplayer crashes with same error

Comment: then check, if You create a exoplayer instance in multiple places in your code

Comment: found the problem, You were right and Your answer is correct..thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is from the Exoplayer Library if you are using version `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.6` and has been fixed. Furthermore, You can check below threads
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/commit/aa4e0080147fe76a6c0cca40b7eccdf45eb58028
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/11149

Comment: thanks, but with 2.18.7 the behaviour still occurred for me, so the workaround from @GGK is still necessary